# Eclipse CDT error "A resource exists with a different case"

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt, case-sensitive

I'm developing a C/C++ Project on Eclipse but, when I compile it, this error comes out:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Sensor_handler'.
A resource exists with a different case: '/Sensor_handler/Debug2/Makefile'.
A resource exists with a different case: '/Sensor_handler/Debug2/Makefile'.
```

This error started appearing when, for my needs, I had to switch the internal compiler to Cygwin compiler (in Windows). I read some solutions on the web but I couldn't really figure out what the problem is (I'm an Eclipse newbie)

Answer (score 0):

The core of Microsoft Windows treats file names as case-insensitive.  The file named "abc" is the same file as "ABC".  However, many tools that can run in Windows consider file names to be case-sensitive.  These circumstances can result in some confusing situations.  Eclipse, even running on Windows, considers file names to be case-sensitive, but apparently (as I don't use it) CDT, when assembling applications to run natively in Windows, considers two file names that differ only by case to be an error situation that it cannot handle.

This error message is stating that there is a file named "/Sensor_handler/Debug2/Makefile" that you're trying to use, but that there is a different file name with that same name, but which differs in case.